# How can I print this format in the list of python

Tags: python, list, printing

Let's say that I have this list in python

```
A = ["(a,1)", "(b,2)", "(c,3)", "(d,4)"]
```

so how can I print it out in the following format:

```
(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4)
```

using one line, better without using for loop
Thanks in advance

Comment: any attempts? You know `ast.literal_eval`?

Answer (score 3):

When A is a list of str:

```
print(', '.join(A))
```

Or more general:

```
print(', '.join(map(str, A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case below code will work

```
print(', '.join(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expression:

```
>>> A = ["(a,1)", "(b,2)", "(c,3)", "(d,4)"]
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[\[\]\"]', r"",",".join(A))
'(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4)'
```